# RealmSwift : Can we implement two filter queries in single line statement?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to implement realm queries of filter in a single statement line like android

Android :

```
   RealmResults<Contact> contactList = realm.where(Contact.class)
            .equalTo(Contact.IS_FORMATTED, Boolean.TRUE)
            .equalTo(Contact.IS_NEW_CONTACT, Boolean.TRUE)
            .findAll();
```

Swift :

How can we implement above query in swift single line statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let contactList = realm.objects(Contact)
    .filter("IS_FORMATTED == true AND IS_NEW_CONTACT == true")
```